# More efficient way to do `Q.slice(a).col(b)` using Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

Is there a more efficient way to extract a column from a cube in Armadillo than `Q.slice(a).col(b)`?

Something like `tube`, but for the last 2 dimensions instead of the first 2.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain a pointer to the first element of the desired column of the desired slice. Then pass that pointer to one of the advanced constructors of the [vec class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col).
Example:

```
cube C(6, 5, 4, fill::randu); // cube with 4 slices

vec v1 = C.slice(2).col(3);  // normal way of extracting a vector

vec v2( &C(0,3,2), C.n_rows, false, false);  // alternative way
```

Note that while this works, it's not safe. If `C` is resized or deleted, `v2` will be using unallocated memory, or memory from a different object. In the first case it may result in a segfault. In the second case it's an information leak.

If `C` is a `const cube`, use [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to strip away the `const` from the obtained pointer. Again, this is not safe.

Comment: Thanks, creative idea! Question: In case I need a copy anyway, is there any benefit in using `vec v2( &C(0,3,2), C.n_rows, true, true)` (forcing the copy)? How would this compare in an application where openMP is used?